# The names/symbol of the blocks in Simulink dissapeared ¡

Tags: matlab, simulink

I don't have much experience with simulink but everything was working fine until the symbols inside the blocks (integrator, merge, unary minus...) dissapeared and now it is just a white square (they continue working tho). I haven't modified the format or similar that I can recall.

I have also tried to delete those blocks and import new ones from the library browser but the problem persist.

How can I fix this problem?

PD: I can't upload an image sorry :((

Comment: Did you try restarting MATLAB? Did you try rebooting your computer? Otherwise, maybe ask customer support, it’s what you pay for.

Comment: You can upload an image without any reputation, it will be inserted as a link to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, I used the next commands in the command window.

```
restoredefaultpath
rehash toolboxcache
```

It will take some time, but might work.